# I need to display html using json encode

Tags: php, json, forms

I have a form and am using json encode. It displays like the below.

[{"approveNight":"A","approve":"A","Comments":"bbb","Email":"email@email.com"}]

I am using this, but I would like it to display html. What am I missing?

```
 <?php 

  $data = array($jsonData);

  echo json_encode($data);
   ?>
```

I would like it to display as

Approve: yes or no
Approve: yes or no
comments: the comments
email: email address that they typed in

Comment: Could you be more specific in your question ? I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: You are missing anything to output html (either echoing it or closing the php and writing yourself).  You encode a string as json data and then echo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see if this helps:

```
$arrValues= json_decode($data);
print 'Approve: '.($arrValues['approve']=='A' ? 'Yes' : 'No').'<br />'
  . 'Comments: '.$arrValues['Comments'].'<br />'
  . 'Email: '.$arrValues['Email'].'<br />'
  . 'Approve Night: '.($arrValues['approveNight']=='A' ? 'Yes' : 'No');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had decode set wrong.

Comment: Good to hear. If you would like to contribute to your own question through posting your working code, please add it as separate answer or extend your code above. And if my answer did help I would appreciate if you'd mark it as an answer ;-)